# send condition GET request(If-Modified-Since,If-None-Match),but can't get a http 304 response

Tags: java, http, jboss

[image]

As you can see, the date of If-Modified-Since is same to Last Modified,and date of If-None-Match is same to Etag,but the server always return a 200 OK status,the server is jboss-4.2.3.GA,what's wrong with it, in this case , I think the server  should return a 304 status.